# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined when the variable is defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am getting a TypeError, while it should not be as I believe I have the variables properly defined (please correct me!)

Already had a look around to try and find it; however, even with the 'fixes' it still gave me the error. I apologise for the error I definitely have made!

```
var parts = message.content.split(" ");
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "sr")) {
  const servguild = message.guild.id;
  const member = message.mentions.members.first();
  const role = servguild.roles.find('name', parts[2]);
  member.addRole(role);
}
```

Comment: What line is causing the error? Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: Keep in mind that not passing a function into [`find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) is deprecated. Better usage: `servguild.roles.find(r => r.name === parts[2])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined servguild as `message.guild.id;`, and are trying to access the `roles` attribute of it and hence trying to access `message.guild.id.roles`. However, the `roles` attribute only exists on the `guild` attribute, not the `guild.id` attribute.

From the [Discord Developer Portal Docs for Guild](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild), you can see that a guild is defined as follows:

```
{
    "id": "41771983423143937",
    "application_id": null,
    "name": "Discord Developers",
    "icon": "86e39f7ae3307e811784e2ffd11a7310",
    "splash": null,
    "owner_id": "80351110224678912",
    "region": "us-east",
    "afk_channel_id": "42072017402331136",
    "afk_timeout": 300,
    "embed_enabled": true,
    "embed_channel_id": "41771983444115456",
    "verification_level": 1,
    "default_message_notifications": 0,
    "explicit_content_filter": 0,
    "mfa_level": 0,
    "widget_enabled": false,
    "widget_channel_id": "41771983423143937",
    "roles": [],
    "emojis": [],
    "features": ["INVITE_SPLASH"],
    "unavailable": false
}
```

To fix your code, change `const servguild = message.guild.id;` to `const servguild = message.guild;`

Comment: Absolute legend!